# compile error when using outer defined variable from inner function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, scope, reference

The following snippet-code complains error saying that "unresolved reference maxFreq":

```
def returnItemsWithMinSupport():
    maxFreq = -1
    def recInFreqSet():
        if 2 > maxFreq:
            maxFreq = 1
        return 3
```

But if I change it to the following, it complains nothing:

```
def returnItemsWithMinSupport():
    maxFreq = -1
    def recInFreqSet():
        if 2 > maxFreq:
            x = 1
        return 3
```

Why is that? Great thanks.

Comment: @Vaulstein, It's not a global variable, but a variable in outer scope.

Comment: You cannot set outer variable  in inner function. If you are using Python 3.x, you can declare the variable as `nonlocal maxFreq` allowing outer variable set.  See [`nonlocal` statemetn](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement).

Comment: @falsetru: Oh sorry. But the first code runs for me

Comment: @Vaulstein, If you actually call `returnItemsWithMinSupport()`, you will see exception. (you need to modify the `returnItemsWithMinSupport` also to call `recInFreqSet`)

Comment: @falsetru Got it, thanks!